# Vim (window-resize): how do I easily make the windows equally high for only one column?

Tags: vim, neovim

I have a vertically split window and the window is further horizontally split within each column. I want to make the height of the windows within one column the same, but do not want to change the heights within the other (let's say, one window in the other column is set to highest possible, like by using <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd><kbd>_</kbd>, and I don't want to change that). What is the easiest way possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `equalalways` is on (it is by default), closing a split resizes the remaining splits to be equal. So just create a new split and then close it.

```
:new | q
```

Mapping it to a key (e.g. <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>) would look like so:

```
nnoremap <Leader>eq :new \| :q<cr>
```

Comment: Oh wow sweet. For those who want to map this sequence, don't forget to add a `'\'` in front of the `'|'`. From `:help :bar` - `'|' can be used to separate commands, so you can give multiple commands in one line.  If you want to use '|' in an argument, precede it with '\'.`

Comment: Yeah, another option would be to execute it as two commands (e.g. `nnoremap <Leader>eq :new<cr>:q<cr>`).

Comment: @OndrejSimek, This is great. May be you can update that this will not work if `equalalways` is off

Comment: @dlmeetei Sure, I've incorporated both comments.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way that I can think of is using a mouse

```
:set mouse+=a
```

and then use your mouse to drag and resize the screen to fit your requirement accordingly.

---

Without the mouse, It is possible but involves extra typing. Go to the column
that you want to resize.
Then `:resize #`, where # is calculated from output of `(set lines -2)/2` where 2 is accounting for `cmdheight` and 1 for `statusline`. The number need to be adjusted accordingly for "cmdheights and statusline". This is cumbersome.

The trick from @Ondrej should be preferred if mouse is disabled in vim

Comment: Actually I'd prefer not to use the mouse, but thanks for your comment!

Comment: Unfortunately, `CTRL-W` followed by `=` makes _all_ windows (not just the ones within the column of interest) equally high and wide, no matter which window you fire it from. Details can be found with `:help window-resize` as I have the keyword in my title.
I guess my question requires a (hopefully) simple Vimscript function. As I'm not familiar with the language, I'm hoping someone who is to kindly answer or wondering whether anyone has already invented the wheel.

Comment: Please see @Ondrej Simek's answer. Thanks for your help again.